# Type casting int and double

Tags: java, casting, integer, double, type-conversion

In the primitive type casting in Java, what would the following code show?

```
float a = 1.11;
int b = a;
int c = (int)a;
System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c);
```

And could a double variable be cast into an int if double is 64 bit and int is 32 bit?

Comment: _"what would the following code show ?"_ Why don't you try yourself ? And it would show nothing since it doesn't compile.

Comment: please ask your question clearly

Comment: why won't it compile?

Comment: Because there is no possible cast from `a` to `b` at compile time; you  would lose precision.

Comment: @fge thanks. that is what i wanted to know.

Comment: just telling that it won't compile is not a solution @ZouZou you should have told the reason. rather than trying to be heroic.

Comment: There is no reason to attack others ;) I can always make an answer of my comment if you like, with more details, but basically you have your answer now ;)

Comment: @micro.pravi I have no need to be _"heroic"_ but you really should try and understand why it would do/show before asking _"What it will show"_ .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your last point which is interesting (the other parts of the question are best answered by a debugger), a double that is too large for an int will cast into the largest possible int; similarly for a double that is too small for an int will cast to the smallest possible int.

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#d5e4334

Note that an int is defined in Java as 32 bits (for eternity) and a double is 64 bit (for eternity).

Answer (score 0):

This will compile:

```
float a = 1.11f;
int b = (int) a;
int c = (int)a;
System.out.println(a + " " + b + " " + c);
```

1. To initialize a `float` variable, you should add `f` at the end of the numerical value.
2. `float`, like a `double`, can not be casted to an `int` type in case if different bit sizes.
3. Next time please use `google.com` to find such answers.